# ExtJS - Json to model parse parent but not childs correctly

Tags: json, parsing, extjs, model

I'm loading a json to my Model but it only recognize the parent model class but not the childs.

This is the json:

```
{
"Feedback": {
    "id": 101,
    "title": "asdsadsa",
    "description": "sadasds",
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 43,
            "feedbackFk": 101,
            "comment": "Hi John , we are glad to receive feedback from you :) \\nOne of our technicians will reach back to you shortly.",
            "commentDate": 1431488907881,
            "owner": {
                "id": 4,
                "firstName": "Arnold",
                "lastName": "Smoth",
                "type": "3",
                "email": "fzegarra@XXXX.com"
            },
            "responses": null,
            "likes": null
        }
    ],
    "attachments": null,
    "createdDate": 1431488906273,
    "lastUpdateDate": 1431488906273,
    "status": "OPEN",
    "source": "ETMS",
    "user": {
        "id": 6,
        "firstName": "John ",
        "lastName": "Travolta",
        "type": "1",
        "email": "john.travolta@XXXXX.com"
    }
}
 }
```

This is parent code:

```
Ext.define('FBT.model.data.Feedback', {
extend: 'FBT.model.data.MappedModel',

fields: [ {
name: 'id',
type: 'auto'
}, {
name: 'title',
type: 'string'
}, {
name: 'description',
type: 'string'
}, {
name: 'createdDate',
type: 'date',
dateFormat: 'time'
}, {
name: 'lastUpdateDate',
type: 'date',
dateFormat: 'time'
}, {
name: 'status',
type: 'string'
}, {
name: 'source',
type: 'string'
} ],

belongsTo: [ {
name: 'reporter',
associationKey: 'user',
model: 'FBT.model.data.User'
} ],

hasMany: [ {
model: 'FBT.model.data.Comment',
name: 'comments',
associationKey: 'comments',
foreignKey: 'feedbackFk'
}, {
model: 'FBT.model.data.Attachment',
name: 'attachments',
associationKey: 'attachments'
} ],

getModelName: function() {
return 'Feedback';
}
 });
```

This is one of the childs

```
Ext.define('FBT.model.data.Comment', {
extend: 'FBT.model.data.MappedModel',

fields: [ {
name: 'id',
type: 'auto'
}, {
name: 'feedbackFk',
type: 'int'
}, {
name: 'comment',
type: 'string'
}, {
name: 'commentDate',
type: 'date',
dateFormat: 'time'
} ],

belongsTo: [ 'Feedback', 'User' ],

hasMany: [ {
model: 'FBT.model.data.Comment',
name: 'responses',
associationKey: 'responses',
}, {
model: 'FBT.model.data.User',
name: 'likes'
} ]
});
```

but when I parse it, Comments are not recognized as a model

[image: As you can see, comments are Object, they should be FBT.model.data.Comment]

Comment: What version of ExtJS do you use ?

Comment: Are you expecting the comments object inside your Feedback instance to be an instance of Model?

Comment: yea, I'm expecting to have each comment (in comments array) to be a instance of FBT.model.data.Comment, but they are instance of Object.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your parent model class (`FBT.model.data.MappedModel`) please ?